# Are shaders the only way to implement 2d lighting?

Tags: java, libgdx, lighting

I'm working on a 2d top down game with libgdx and I think i got the basics. No want I want to implement lighting, I don't know anything about lighting. I want just to have some light sources and shadows, but how do i do it?

**Is using glsgl the only wayto do lighting in a 2d game?** I've already tried to learn opengl and gave up because i thought it was too dificult and could take too long to do something even if i got the basics. Mabye glsl is different anyways

Any examples/tutorials would be welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not lighting, but I already did shadow projections of 2d sprites with simple Quads. It results in this kind of shadows seen in The King of Fighters for example: http://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx2/game/kof13cards/kof13-card25.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do dynamic lighting without shaders, although they're usually not as efficient. They often involve raycasting. The link below has some links to useful resources regarding dynamic lighting.

http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/2d-dynamic-lighting/27012/view.html

Comment: what do you mean by "not as effecient"?

Comment: Since shaders are run on the GPU, which has much faster memory and can perform mathematical operations a lot faster and output it to the screen. This is one of the reasons shaders are more popular than other methods, like drawing to a surface and subtracting/adding the appropriate areas.

Answer (score 1):

If you're also working with box2D, you could try box2Dlights, it's a pretty nice wrapper and it's easy to implement as well.

Comment: isn't it java-only?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but you posted in the java category so that shouldn't really be a problem